# Limit API Calls, Microsoft Cognitive Services Bing News API

Tags: azure, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I signed up for the paid Microsoft Cognitive Services Bing News API.

`Is there a way in the Cognitive Services API's to limit calls so billing doesn't get out of control?`

For example it would be great if the account shut down at 100k calls a month VS the default which allows the calls to go over and charges me overages of $30 per 10k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in throttle mechanisms in the Cognitive Services API's (aside from the free tier which limits monthly access).

You'll need to build some type of metering into your app to be aware of call counts (and how you accomplish that is really up to you).